# Postgresql unable to start: No space left on device

Tags: postgresql

I have taken dump for the db and it make it run short of memory for Postgresql.
I have then restarted postgresql but it failed to restart.And kept on giving me error

```
[FAIL] Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server: main[....] The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: ... failed!
 failed!
```

and in log file there were following lines

```
2017-05-05 05:49:25 UTC LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2017-05-05 05:49:30 UTC LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2017-05-05 05:49:35 UTC LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2017-05-05 05:49:35 UTC LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2017-05-05 05:49:35 UTC LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_85990.tmp": No space left on device
2017-05-05 05:49:35 UTC LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2017-05-05 05:49:40 UTC LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2017-05-05 05:49:40 UTC LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2017-05-05 05:49:45 UTC LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
```

Please Help me to solve this issue if some one can.
thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether there is enough space left on your device?

Comment: can you help me to check and free some space?

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not user support (like "how do I delete files").

Comment: okay thank you for your time @melpomene

Comment: I have deleted some log files but still unable to restart postgres

Comment: "_Devide_" means your physical drive, how much free space you have on your disks so the database can start
Look for the database configuration file (**postgresql.conf**), it can give you a clue how much space you need to start
Try to check a possible solution in PostgreSql documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs